# Getting empty values for "DateComposed" and "timeComposed"

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

I am trying to read "DateComposed" and "timeComposed" values of Notes Discussion Database using Domino.dll.  While reading I am getting "" for both of them.

Sample code:

```
DateTime  DiaryDate     = (DateTime)((object[])docJournal.GetItemValue("DateComposed"))[0];
DateTime  dtTimeCreated = (DateTime)((object[])docJournal.GetItemValue("timeComposed"))[0];
```

Is there another way to read them?

Answer (score 1):

Try the document "GetItemValueDateTimeArray" method instead of "GetItemValue"

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the DateComposed and TimeComposed fields are "Computed for Display" fields, meaning these are not actual fields stored on the document, but are computed on the fly when a document is rendered through a form. In looking at the form design of the out-of-the-box Notes Discussion template, I see those two fields are computed based on the document's internal created date.  So, take a look at the getCreated method, which returns a DateTime. You can then parse out the date and time values.

Try something like this:

```
...
Document docJournal = ...
DateTime DiaryDate = docJournal.getCreated().getLocalTime();
...
```